# How to do a permutation and combination inside a json in python

Tags: python, json, python-itertools

I have a Json data, such as:

```
{ 
    "id" : "d231e2ba-cd97-11e8-bc2a-02420afe4907", 
    "name": "devices",
     "policy_rules" : [
          { "name" : "rule-1",...},
          { "name" : "rule-2",...},
          { "name" : "rule-3",...},
          ...
          { "name" : "rule-n",...}
      ]
}
```

I want to do a permutation, to output all the possible json data sets, each of which may contain 1 to n rules, and the order of rules also matters.

Does anyone know how this can be done in python ?

Comment: What do you mean under 'permutation' here? If you already have that JSON all you need is to get the `policy_rules` list which will contain all of your _rules_. If you need to generate it, there are no permutations - just use `range(1, n+1)` to generate a list of rules from `1` to `n`.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me which parts of your question you're asking about. Do you know how to parse (and maybe recreate) your JSON data, or is that what you need help with? (If that's the case, the permutation parts of the question are irrelevant.) Or do you know about the `json` module and just need help with the permutation part? (If so, explain it better, perhaps with examples, and consider getting rid of the JSON part of the question, as it's irrelevant to the permutation part.)

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new to python.  I need to know a) how to retrieve the policy_rule part from this json. b) for the rules within the policy_rule section, how to generate all the combinations. c) And for each possibility, to have the id, name, policy_rules packed back into one json object.